# Sass gem conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, git-bash

When I desire to start the server in my GitBash, I get the next message in red letters:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    sass (= 3.5)

  In Gemfile:
    sass (= 3.5) x86-mingw32

    compass (>= 1.0.3, ~> 1.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
      sass (< 3.5, >= 3.3.13) x86-mingw32

    sass-rails (>= 5.0.7, ~> 5.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      sass (~> 3.1) x86-mingw32

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I really have been breaking my head on this for the past few hours. Could somebody help?

Comment: Did you run `bundle update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing sass-rails  with gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0.0.beta1' will resolve your issue. and use sass version 3.4

if you don't want to go for a beta version of sass rails then you have to downgrade compass to gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.1'.